# Добавление приложения в App Store

Tags: xcode, swift, appstore

Приветствую!
Подскажите, если я выкладываю второе приложение в App Store, то порядок действий отличается каким-либо образом или нет? К примеру, может сертификаты какие-то повторно делать не требуется или еще что-то?
А то начал грузить приложение, а оно выдает ошибку как на картинке и не знаю как решить данную проблему(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду признателен за помощь)

Comment: Подсказали как решить проблему. Сделал анчек Automatically Code Signing  и чекнул обратно. Проблема исчезла :)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно поставить и убрать галочку Automaticlly Code Signing в начтройка самого проекта.

Comment: Упс уже увидел что проблема решена.